# Ansible connect to jump machine through VPN?

Tags: ansible

I was wondering if it were possible to tell Ansible to set up a VPN connection before executing the rest of the playbook. I've googled around, but haven't seen much on this.

Comment: Not easily but you could wrap your `ansible` command in a shell script or something else that could set up the VPN/check the VPN is up first. To do it entirely in Ansible is probably going to involve a local playbook that is just shelling out anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You could combine a [local playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks) to setup a VPN and a playbook to run your tasks against a server.

Depending on whats the job you can use ansible or a shell script to connect the VPN. Maybe there should be another playbook to disconnect afterwards.

As result you will have three playbooks and one to combine them via include:

```
- include: connect_vpn.yml
- include: do_stuff.yml
- include: disconnect_vpn.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [How To Use Ansible and Tinc VPN to Secure Your Server Infrastructure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ansible-and-tinc-vpn-to-secure-your-server-infrastructure).

Basically, you need to install [`thisismitch/ansible-tinc`](https://github.com/thisismitch/ansible-tinc) playbook and create a `hosts` inventory file with the nodes that you want to include in the VPN, for example:

```
[vpn]
prod01 vpn_ip=10.0.0.1 ansible_host=162.243.125.98
prod02 vpn_ip=10.0.0.2 ansible_host=162.243.243.235
prod03 vpn_ip=10.0.0.3 ansible_host=162.243.249.86
prod04 vpn_ip=10.0.0.4 ansible_host=162.243.252.151

[removevpn]
```

Then you should review the contents of the `/group_vars/all` file such as:

```
---

netname: nyc3
physical_ip: "{{ ansible_eth1.ipv4.address }}"

vpn_interface: tun0

vpn_netmask: 255.255.255.0
vpn_subnet_cidr_netmask: 32
```

where:

- `physical_ip` is IP address which you want *tinc* to bind to;
- `vpn_netmask` is the netmask that the will be applied to the VPN interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Amazon Web Services, check out the [`ec2_vpc_vpn` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ec2_vpc_vpn_module.html) which can create, modify, and delete VPN connections. It uses `boto3`/`botocore` library.

For example:

```
- name: create a VPN connection
  ec2_vpc_vpn:
    state: present
    vpn_gateway_id: vgw-XXXXXXXX
    customer_gateway_id: cgw-XXXXXXXX

- name: delete a connection
  ec2_vpc_vpn:
    vpn_connection_id: vpn-XXXXXXXX
    state: absent
```

---

For other cloud services, check the [list of Ansible Cloud Modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/list_of_cloud_modules.html).